# How to change single value in json data with axios

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when I want to update my password with a menu change password. when I use Axios.put the data still not change, I already tried to search but no one same with my problem. I just need to know how to change the single value like a password with Axios put

**changepassword.js**

```js
import React,{Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody,
    FormGroup,
    Form,
    Label,
    Input,
    Container,
    Button,
    Row,
    Col,
    Alert
  } from "reactstrap";
import UserHeader from "components/Headers/UserHeader.js";


const customHistory = createHashHistory();  


class SetPass extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const email= localStorage.getItem("email");
    const password = localStorage.getItem("password");

    let isLogedIn = true
    if (token === null || email=== null || password === null) {
        isLogedIn = false
    }
        this.state = {
            post : [],
            formData : {
        id : '',
        first_name : '',
        last_name : '',
        email : '',
        gender : '',
        password: '',
        confirm : ''
      },
      isLogedIn

        }

        this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }


    getPostAPI = () => {
    const email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState ({
        post : res.data
      })
    })
  }

  putDataToAPI = () => {
  const email = localStorage.getItem("email");
  axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}/${this.state.formData.id}`, {
     password : this.state.formData.password

    })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState ({
        formData : {
          password: '',
          confirm : ''
        },
      })
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    // 
    // console.log(axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}`, this.state.formData.password))
    // axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}/`, this.state.formData.password)
    // .then (res => {          
    //   console.log(res);
    //   this.setState ({
    //     formData : {
    //       id : '',
    //       password: '',
    //       confirm : ''
    //     },
    //   })
    // })
    // .catch (err => {
    //   console.log(err);
    // })
  }

    handleForm = (e) => {
        let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
        formDataNew[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            formData : formDataNew
        })

  }



    submit = () => {
    const {post} = this.state;
    const email= localStorage.getItem("email");
    const password = localStorage.getItem("password");  

        if((this.state.formData['password'] === "") || (this.state.formData['confirm'] === "") ) {
        alert("Semua Data Harus Di Isi!!!");  
    } else

    if(this.state.formData['password'] !== this.state.formData['confirm']) {
        alert("Password tidak sama dengan Confirm Password")
    } else

    if(post.find(e =>  `${e.email}${e.password}` === `${email}${password}` )) {
       this.putDataToAPI();
       alert('Sukses Ganti Password')
    } 
  }


    componentDidMount () {
        this.getPostAPI();
    }


    render(){


    if (this.state.isLogedIn === false) {
      customHistory.push('/')
    } 
        return (         
          <Fragment>
          <UserHeader />
          <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col className="order-xl-1" xl="8">
              <Card className="bg-secondary shadow">
                <CardHeader className="bg-white border-0">
                  <Row className="align-items-center">
                    <Col xs="8">
                      <h3 className="mb-0">CHANGE PASSWORD</h3>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="text-right" xs="4">
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <Form>
                 <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
                    <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={this.state.formData.password} type="password"  name = "password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
                 </FormGroup>
                 <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="confirm">Confirm Password</Label>
                    <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={this.state.formData.confirm} type="password"  name = "confirm" className="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="" />
                 </FormGroup>
                      <Button onClick={this.submit} className="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                </Form>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

function select(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
}

export default connect(select)(SetPass);
```

update changepassword.js

```
putDataToAPI = () => {
    const email = localStorage.getItem("username");
    const { post } = this.state
    {
      post.map(post => (

        axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin/${post.id}?email=${email}`, {
          ...this.post,
          password : this.state.formData.password,

          })
          .then(response => {
            this.setState ({
              formData : {
                password: '',
                confirm : ''
              },
            })
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
      ))
    }
  }
```

I expect when form click submit, the value of password was changed. but still no change. is there any chance to change this without id?

Comment: please share your all code changepassword.js file

Comment: It depends on what your backend expects/supports.

Comment: what do u mean ? i just use json data fake jsoon server . with axios

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for your URL in

```
putDataToAPI = () => {
  const email = localStorage.getItem("email");
  axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}/${this.state.formData.id}`, {
     password : this.state.formData.password

    })
```

It's messed up. Instead of *`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin?email=${email}/${this.state.formData.id}`*, it should be **`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin/${this.state.formData.id}?email=${email}`**
Plus, don't forget to add the second field:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/dataadmin/${this.state.formData.id}?email=${email}`, {
     password : this.state.formData.password,
     confirm : this.state.formData.confirm
    })
```

Comment: look at more broo.  this form just input not detil . if detil we can use this. but if just form ? thats why i send the email and password to localstorage. and want to (if input === localstorage.get email then password will be change . 

my question how make query like update password from table dataadmin where email = localstorage get email. ahhaha

Comment: Why would you store the password in the local storage in the first place? Absolutely do not!!!

Comment: ya im sorry, i will delete it soon.

Comment: You have an implementation issue on the server. To use 'PUT' with RESTful APIs, you have to identify the resource to modify in the URL and pass in the body the parts of the object you wish to alter. Plus, in your ```putDataToAPI ()``` method, you pass only one property (the password) but in your form, you require the **password** and **confirm** password fields.

Comment: i try to modify the body , i use post.map (post => bla bll. and i try to pop up the id . it return id that i login into dashboard. for the example. i login with email aaa@gmail.com with id = 4 in json data. and return 4 because my getpost api return email in localstorage..

Comment: my big problm how to change password in json-data . i already tried many times. still no changes

Comment: still no changes broo

Comment: yess i already changes it . but the data become id , password, confirm, i want to keep the data except password